# Selenium Python Windows Chrome. Как загрузить файл(ы) из компьютера по относительному или полному пути

Tags: python, windows, файлы, selenium, google-chrome

[image: загрузить файл из компьютера]

```
#элемент отвечающий за открыть окно "вставку изображения из компьютера"

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='SHORTCUT_FOCUSABLE_DIV']/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[16]/div").click()
```

Каким образом можно вставить файлы или файлы указав полный путь или относительный? И нажать на кнопку открыть.

Comment: почитайте это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

Используй класс Robot, который будет вводить путь и нажимать кнопку "Открыть".

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться automate 7 (или 10) упростить задачу, но не для фоновых задач